# Not able to pass the Data by using Future COMBINE iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, alamofire, combine

I'm using Alamofire for data downloading and passing the data by using Future Publisher and in another class I'm accessing that data and decoding the JsonData and again passing it by using another future. But some times I'm successfully showing in UI and sometimes it's not working.

extension HTTPManager: NetworkManager {

```
fun getData(from urlString: String) -> Future<Data, Error> {
    return Future { promise in
        AF.request(urlString).response { responseData in
            switch responseData.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                promise(.failure(error))
            case .success(let data):
                guard let data = data else { return }
                promise(.success(data))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
fun fetchDetailData() -> Future<[DetailViewModel], Error> {
    return Future { [self] promise in
        let resultData = self.networkManager.getData(from: self.urlString)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
        resultData.sink { (completion) in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                promise(.failure(error))
            case .finished:
                debugPrint("api call successful")
            }
        } receiveValue: { (data) in
            do {
                let detailData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Detail].self, from: data)
                let detailsData = detailData.map {
                    DetailViewModel(with: $0)
                }
                promise(.success(detailsData))
            }
            catch let jsonError {
                promise(.failure(jsonError))
            }
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}


fun fetchDetailsData() {
    self.subscriber = DetailServiceManager().fetchDetailData()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint("Error Occured", error)
            case .finished:
                debugPrint("Api call is successful")
            }
        } receiveValue: { detailData in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.detailsData = detailData
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: No need to use `Future`, Alamofire offers native publishers. `.publishDecodable([Detail].self)` should get you started.